# Benchmarks like Antutu/GeekBench for Windows PC?

Tags: windows, benchmarking

Can anyone tell benchmark/scoring programs for Windows PC. I am not considering the score in Windows Settings, only third-party tools. There are plenty for Android like Antutu or Geekbench. I want something on similar lines which people use to score different desktops/laptops.

Answer (score 2):

Try PassMark Software http://www.passmark.com/products/pt.htm

The benchmark score we use to rank PCs is known as The PassMark Rating, which is obtained by users after running the full suite of tests available from PerformanceTest. The PassMark Rating is a unique performance rating for a machine's configuration and is calculated from a machine's performance over six test suites, comprised of twenty-eight unique tests designed to cover all aspects of computing performance.

More specifically, the PassMark Rating is calculated from a series of weighted averages, where some system components are considered to be more critical to system performance based on "average" computer usage. Our rating is also calculated in such a way that all computer components must be performing well in order for the final result to be exceptional - that is, a single extremely high value for one component will not significantly improve the final PassMark Rating.

PCs with a bigger PassMark Rating score are considered to be faster and better performing computers overall. For example, an Intel Pentium 4 3.20GHz may have a PassMark Rating of about 700, while a Core2 Duo E8500 with 3GB of RAM may have a PassMark Rating around 1250.

Answer (score 1):

Geekbench is available for Windows PCs: http://www.primatelabs.com/geekbench/

Geekbench scores are comparable across platforms, too, so you can compare the performance of your Windows PC against the performance of your Android phone.